# cli_scangpt: detected a non-protective MBR

Tags: 14.04, mbr, clamav

I am running `clamscan` on my system with following command

```
sudo clamscan --max-filesize=3999M --max-scansize=3999M --exclude-dir=/sys/* -i -r /
```

received the message

```
LibClamAV Warning: cli_scangpt: detected a non-protective MBR
```

What does it mean? What do I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a `clamav` specialist but given the name of the tool showing the warning `cli_scangpt`, this is tool give you a warning that a GPT partition does not have a *protective MBR*.

According to this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Protective_MBR_.28LBA_0.29), a protective MBR is used to prevent MBR partitioning tools to overwrite GPT disks by accident.

Since you're using an antivirus, I assume you were asking if there is a security risk related to this warning, and I don't see any security implication with that problem, so you can probably safely ignore it.